# How to subset a data.frame in R using parameters?

Tags: r, parameters, dataframe

I have the following problem: I want to subset a data.frame using parameters.
From command line (without parameters) its working, but fails when I try to switch to parameters:

```
    party = c(10,11,12,13,14) 
    s2 = c(11,22,33,44,55) 
    s3 = c(511,522,533,544,555) 
    s = data.frame(party,s2,s3) 
    u = s[s$party == 12,]
```

works.

The same with parameters:

```
     var1 = "party"
     party_id = 12
     u = s[as.character(paste0("s$",var1," == ",party_id,","))]
```

fails with: "*undefined columns selected*".

What's wrong here?
What is the desired form, R anticipates?

Comment: Use `s[[var1]] == party_id`

Comment: you just forgot a comma. this works:
    `u = s[as.character(paste0("s$",var1," == ",party_id,",")),]`, *this doesn't work*.

Comment: sorry this works correctly: `u = s[eval(parse(text=as.character(paste0("s$",var1," == ",party_id))))
,]`

Comment: Okay, though that's really not a good way to do it.

Comment: I agree your way is much better, but it's closer to the code lmocsi wrote.

Comment: Thanks, bjoseph's eval() solution works fine. I'm disappointed to see that such a simple task has only a solution this complicated (4 embedded functions).